# How to delete worksheet in PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel, worksheet

In PHPExcel how can I delete a sheet with the name **worksheet**?

I have this, but it does not work:

```
$objWorkSheet->removeSheetByIndex("Worksheet");
```

Comment: Fix some spelling and rearrange title

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Worksheet` is the name of a worksheet, not its index (position within the collection of worksheets). You need to identify its index position and use that as the argument to `removeSheetByIndex()`

Something like:

```
$objWorkSheet->setActiveSheetIndexByName('Worksheet');
$sheetIndex = $objWorkSheet->getActiveSheetIndex();
$objWorkSheet->removeSheetByIndex($sheetIndex);
```

or

```
$objWorkSheet->removeSheetByIndex(
    $objWorkSheet->getIndex(
        $objWorkSheet->getSheetByName('Worksheet')
    )
);
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me. There is no `removeSheetByIndex()` method of my worksheet.

Comment: @ZoltánSüle - No there isn't, not on the `worksheet` object.... OP was assigning their `PHPExcel` object to `$objWorksheet`, which might have confused you.... the method is against the `PHPExcel` object